# Basic Java application data storage

Tags: java

I'm working on (essentially) a calendar application written in Java, and I need a way to store calendar events. This is the first "real" application I've written, as opposed to simple projects (usually for classes) that either don't store information between program sessions or store it as text or .dat files in the same directory as the program, so I have a few *very* basic questions about data storage.

- How should the event objects and other data be stored? (.dat files, database of some type, etc)
- Where should they be stored?
- I'm guessing it's not good to load all the objects into memory when the program starts and not update them on the hard drive until the program closes. So what do I do instead?

If there's some sort of tutorial (or multiple tutorials) that covers the answers to my questions, links to those would be perfectly acceptable answers.

(I know there are somewhat similar questions already asked, but none of them I could find address a complete beginner perspective.)

EDIT: Like I said in one of the comments, in general with this, I'm interested in using it as an opportunity to learn how to do things the "right" (reasonably scalable, reasonably standard) way, even if there are simpler solutions that would work in this basic case.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers! Under my particular circumstances, Bruno's answer is the most helpful to me because it goes beyond what I know already, which is what I'm wanting to do with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a quick solution, if your data structures (and of course the way you access them) are sufficiently simple, reading and writing the data to files, using your own format (e.g. binary, XML, ...), or perhaps standard formats such as [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) might be more suited to your problem. Libraries such as [iCal4J](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html) might help you with that.

Taking into account the more general aspects of your question, this is a broader topic, but you may want to read about databases (relational or not). Whether you want to use them or not will depend on the overall complexity of your application.

A number of relational databases can be used in Java using [JBDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). This should allow you to connect to the relational database ([SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)) of your choice. Some of them run within their own server application (e.g. MS SQL, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL), but some of them can be embedded within your Java application, for example: [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) (a variant of Apache Derby DB, only included in Java versions 5 to 7), [Apache Derby DB](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or SQLite.

These embeddable SQL databases will essentially store the data on files on the same machine the application is running on (in a format specific to them), but allow you to use the data using SQL queries.
The benefits include a certain structure to your data (which you build when designing your tables and possible constraints) and (when supported by the engine) the ability to handle concurrent access via [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). Even in a desktop application, this may be useful.

This may imply a learning curve if you have to learn SQL, but it should save you the trouble of handling the details of defining your own file format. Giving structure to your data via SQL (often known by other developers) can be better than defining your own data structures that you would have to save into and read from your own files anyway.

In addition, if you want to deal with objects directly, without knowing much about SQL, you may be interested in [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) frameworks such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). Their aim is to hide the SQL details from you by being able to store/load objects directly. Not everyone likes them and they also come with their own learning curve (which may entail learning some details of how SQL works too). Their pros and cons could be discussed at length (there are certainly questions about this on StackOverflow or even DBA.StackExchange).

There are also other forms of databases, for example XML databases or Semantic-Web/RDF databases, which may or may not suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

> How should the event objects and other data be stored? (.dat files,
>   database of some type, etc)

It depends on the size of the data to be stored (and loaded), and if you want to be able to perform queries on your data or not.

> Where should they be stored?

A file in the user directory (or in a subdirectory of the user directory) is a good choice. Use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to get it.

> I'm guessing it's not good to load all the objects into memory when
>   the program starts and not update them on the hard drive until the
>   program closes. So what do I do instead?

It might be a perfectly valid thing to do, unless the amount of data is so great that it would eat far too much memory. I don't think it would be a problem for a simple calendar application. If you don't want to do that, then store the events in a database and perform queries to only load the events that must be displayed.

Comment: In general with this, I'm interested in using it as an opportunity to learn how to do things the "right" (reasonably scalable, reasonably standard) way. So I'd rather not store information right in the user's home directory, because that's often not where it belongs. In a real Java application, would the developers just have to account for the "proper" location of application data for all the OSes they choose to support?

Comment: Also, I'm a little worried about not saving the data until the application closes, at least for something like a calendar--what if it crashes, or otherwise doesn't close in a way that triggers the data to be saved?

Comment: If it's a user application, IMO, the user home is where the data belongs. Or just let the user choose the file where he wants to save its data, as any office application. You may also have a Save action in the GUI allowing the user to save when he wants to, like any other office app.

Comment: This isn't an office application, so I'm not really dealing with documents. I'm dealing with data that's saved automatically somewhere behind the scenes (which is standard for calendar-type applications), and the only time a user would manually save it would be if they exported it. Also, that behind the scenes place is generally not the user's home directory--on Windows it's one of the Application Data folders, and on Mac it's (home directory)/Library/Application Support.

Answer (score 1):

A simple sequential file should suffice. Basically, each line in your file represents a record, or in your case an event. Separate each field in your records with a field delimiter, something like the pipe (`|`) symbol works nice. Remember to store each record in the same format, for example:

```
date|description|etc
```

This way you can read back each line in the file as a record, extract the fields by splitting the string on your delimiter (`|`) symbol, and use the data.

Storing the data in the same folder as your application should be fine.

The best way I find to handle the objects (for the most part), is to determine whether or not the amount of data you are storing is going to be large enough to have consequences on the user's memory. Based on your description, it should be fine in this program.

Comment: Why not use something like an XML or JSON file, which would make the parser trivial, and handle newlines and separator char in the description without any problem?

Comment: That would work completely fine, I just figured for a small application like this there would be no harm in using a more basic file structure.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I already know how to do, and I'd like to go a little beyond that in sophistication (for learning purposes). Also the idea of using a separator like the pipe worries me a little because it's something the user could easily insert into a data field and it would throw off the parser.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer depends on details, but probably you want to write your events to a database. There are several good free databases out there, like MySQL and Postgres, so you can (relatively) easily grab one and play with it.

Learning to use a database well is a big subject, bigger than I'm going to answer in a forum post. (I could recommend that you read my book, "A Sane Approach to Database Design", but making such a shameless plug on a forum would be tacky!)

Basically, though, you want to read the data from the database when you need it, and update it when it changes. Don't read everything at start up and write it all back at shut-down.

If the amount of data is small and rarely changes, keeping it all in memory and writing it to a flat file is simpler and faster. But most applications don't fit that description.